# Sizeof output is not as expected

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, sizeof, strlen

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char str[400] = "rQvqQmyl9N9FmI8ECESs0N2dKBATuIrvT4HEh0lRa+6kGHIP0owiFqFdlvktmOQMTdZ5gW44G2O6T2uQGlIeeobnyYuZscLadvyM5tkzb1MhEmBoIuCp8db9GZ8SBBMnoDIWNi9Ad6pRzBpcxmobWJnJo3O6BQ/Kii03RMfXVEw5No7n576J0blLPirrH6M7OaIp7qcrT7hD4qHkGIKjoAcGLsu0c5Ii2r+lOnFE1zgMPZtw8+QoHBp/lzFH5LyB973e+k9B5T3UO/L7xM6h8ZN4ufXibM385PdzPuwZ3NbmZRCSpIrvGNyUSZo0/mcPuzt6KuoQpNLYt9Avmi";
   // Extract the first token
   char * token = strtok(str, " ");
   printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing the token
   printf("%lu \n", sizeof(token));
   return 0;
}
```

Output
rQvqQmyl9N9FmI8ECESs0N2dKBATuIrvT4HEh0lRa+6kGHIP0owiFqFdlvktmOQMTdZ5gW44G2O6T2uQGlIeeobnyYuZscLadvyM5tkzb1MhEmBoIuCp8db9GZ8SBBMnoDIWNi9Ad6pRzBpcxmobWJnJo3O6BQ/Kii03RMfXVEw5No7n576J0blLPirrH6M7OaIp7qcrT7hD4qHkGIKjoAcGLsu0c5Ii2r+lOnFE1zgMPZtw8+QoHBp/lzFH5LyB973e+k9B5T3UO/L7xM6h8ZN4ufXibM385PdzPuwZ3NbmZRCSpIrvGNyUSZo0/mcPuzt6KuoQpNLYt9Avmi

8

Why Size of token is 8 ?
It should be length of token.

Comment: `sizeof(token)` is the size of a pointer. Please use `strlen()`.

Comment: This code illustrates the difference between an array and a pointer.

Comment: Another illustration would be with say `char str[40] = "abc";`  checking the difference between `sizeof str` and `strlen(str)`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `token` has the type `char *` that is it is a pointer

```
char * token = strtok(str, " ");
```

So this call of `printf`

```
printf("%lu \n", sizeof(token));
```

outputs the size of a pointer in your system.

You will get the same result if you will use even an uninitialized pointer that does not point to any string as for example

```
char *token;
printf( "%zu \n", sizeof(token));
```

If you want to output the length of the pointed string then you need to write

```
printf("%zu \n", strlen(token));
```

Answer (score 0):

The eight is the size of your pointer which is platform dependent. What you need is to iterate through the `token` variable or use `strlen(token)` to get the actual size.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is for managing memory, not data. It tells you how much memory a type requires. `sizeof` an array is the number of bytes the array requires. `sizeof` a pointer is the number of bytes the pointer requires.

`strlen` is for managing the data of strings. It tells you how long a string is, which is the number of non-zero characters before the first zero character.